# How to call twice a service that is called in a ngrx effect?

Tags: angular, typescript, redux, rxjs, ngrx

I have an effect that is listening an action, this effect is calling the api (retrieve 10 random movies) once time, this a normal behavior, but I want to call the same service twice.

```
loadMovies$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
   ofType('[Movies Page] Load 20 Movies'),
   mergeMap(() => this.moviesService.getTenRandomMovies()
      .pipe(
        map(movies => ({ type: '[Movies API] 10 Movies Loaded Success', payload: movies })),
        catchError(() => EMPTY)
     ))
   )
 );
```

I was thinking in this solution, but is looking odd. Let me know if this the only possibility.

```
 dispatchTwiceGetAuthQuestions$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType('[Movies Page] Load 20 Movies'),
        tap(() => {
          this.store.dispatch(new LoadTenRandomMovies()); 
        }),
        tap(() => {
            this.store.dispatch(new LoadTenRandomMovies()); 
        })
    )
);


loadMovies$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
   ofType('[Movies Page] Load 10 Movies'),
   mergeMap(() => this.moviesService.getTenRandomMovies()
      .pipe(
        map(movies => ({ type: '[Movies API] 10 Movies Loaded Success', payload: movies })),
        catchError(() => EMPTY)
     ))
   )
 );
```

Note: is not possible to update the backend.

Comment: Any update on this question?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a new function `moviesService.getRandomMovies(pagesToGet: int)`

```
let observables: any[] = [];

for (let i = 0; i < pagesToGet; i ++)
{
    observables.push(this.getTenRandomMovies());
}

return forkJoin(observables)
    .pipe(map(results => results.flat()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using forkJoin should be enough

```
loadMovies$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
   ofType('[Movies Page] Load 10 Movies'),
   switchMap(() => 
      forkJoin([
             this.moviesService.getTenRandomMovies(), 
             this.moviesService.getTenRandomMovies()
      ])
      .pipe(
        map(([response1,response2]) => {
          // do something
        }),
        map(movies => ({ type: '[Movies API] 10 Movies Loaded Success', payload: movies 
       })),
        catchError(() => EMPTY)
     ))
   )
 );
```